# Ionic Cordova OneSignal + Huawei InAppAlert Issue

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, onesignal, huawei-mobile-services

I have an existing Ionic Cordova app where i have set the inFocusDisplaying to use OSInFocusDisplayOption.InAppAlert and it works well in Android and IOS. However when i try to setup it for Huawei devices, the InAppAlert doesn't work and it only shows the Notification Banner.

Does anyone know if the InAppAlert should work in Huawei devices as well ?

**Using the following setup/plugins**

```
Cordova v10.0.0
Cordova-Android v9.1.0
onesignal-cordova-plugin v2.11.4
@ionic-native/onesignal v5.33.1
@hmscore/ionic-native-hms-push v5.1.1-301
@hmscore/cordova-plugin-hms-push v5.1.1-301
```

**Code to initialize OneSignal**

```
this.oneSignal.startInit('myappid');
this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.InAppAlert);
this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe('mycallback');
this.oneSignal.endInit();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the oneSignal [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/sdk-reference#app-in-focus-notification-display), this interface is deprecated .

> [image: Blockquote]

So as an alternative,you may use the new `setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler` method (But I am not sure whether the OneSignal supports this function of the HMS) or you can use huawei push kit directly,which aslo supports this capability.

For details, check this [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-fgrd-show-0000001050040126-V5).

Comment: Hi Shirley, the setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler is only available in the latest beta version of the OneSignal, since it's still beta, I'm not using it for production usage and the inFocusDisplaying is still relevant to the version im using

Comment: Sorry we dont know OneSignal so much :( ,You can confirm with OneSignal Technical Support,or you may can use the HMS Push capability as an alternative like i answered above.